# R xts: transform all 0 values in a time series with the last found value different than 0

Tags: r, transform, xts

I am working on an xts object that contains some 0s in one of the columns and I need to replace them with the last value different than 0 found in the sequence.

For example, I am simplifying here using a regular R vector:

```
v = c(1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0)
```

I need to change all the 0s with the last value != 0 in the sequence, in this case 3. The resulting vector should be:

```
> v
[1] 1 2 3 3 3 3
```

How can I achieve this, possibly using transform() or another vector operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the zeros to `NA` and use `na.locf`:

```
x <- .xts(c(1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0), 1:6)
x[x==0] <- NA
na.locf(x)
```